# Get "SocketException: No route to host" instead of the expected "SocketTimeoutException"

Tags: android, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

I use the `DefaultHttpClient` to fulfill several downlaods. In the case when the enternet is absent I get `SocketTimeoutException` only for my first download, and for the next downloads I get  `java.net.SocketException: No route to host`.Why does it occur? I use new `httpClient`  for each request. I need to get `SocketTimeoutException` for each request, because I should keep the timeout delay between downloads attempts.

Comment: Is in Manifest all Permissions are OK?

Comment: It's OK.Problem that I get SocketException: No route to host instead of the expected SocketTimeoutException

Comment: Checkout this answers:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031170/android-httpurlconnection-httppost-receive-a-socketexception-no-route-to-host

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788163/android-app-java-net-socketexception-no-route-to-host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this answers:

[Android HttpUrlConnection HttpPost receive a SocketException: no route to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031170/android-httpurlconnection-httppost-receive-a-socketexception-no-route-to-host)

[Android App - Java.Net.SocketException: No route to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788163/android-app-java-net-socketexception-no-route-to-host)

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7906834/281545) some explanation :

> Your 192.168.1.114 address is a DHCP address (dynamically) assigned by
>   your router to your PC. As a result it is visible to the emulator.
>
> But depending on how your WiFi is set up, the Android is probably on a
>   different router / subnet and can't see 192.168.1.114. You could check
>   that by typing 192.168.1.114 into the address bar of the Android
>   browser.
>
> If 192.168.1.114 is not visible to your Android, then you will have to
>   either change the routing rules on your router to make it visible, or
>   add a DNS lookup for it.