# Connection between Android and C# application

Tags: java, c#, android

I'm trying to send a simple string between Android device and a C# application

on android as client

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.136",80);
                DataOutputStream DOS = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                DOS.writeUTF("HELLO_WORLD");
                socket.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    thread.start();
```

on the PC as a server using C#

```
        byte[] byteReadStream = null; 
        IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        TcpListener tcpl = new TcpListener(ipe);
        while (true)
        {
            tcpl.Start();
            TcpClient tcpc = tcpl.AcceptTcpClient();
            byteReadStream = new byte[tcpc.Available];
            tcpc.GetStream().Read(byteReadStream, 0, tcpc.Available);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.Default.GetString(byteReadStream) + "\n");
        }
```

I have tried using specific IP and port it did not work

Bluetooth did not work

I have tried several posted codes on this site, all did not work. So maybe there this something that I am missing.

Please advice me on how to fix the code or a better way to send a string between android and windows app in any instant way.

Comment: I'm not sure but you are opening a socket on port 80 and the other problem is that your socket in C# is not listening on a specific port...

Comment: The client expects the server to listen on port 80. But the server listens on a random port. Specify a concrete port in the IPEndPoint constructor. And then use the same port in the client

Comment: @NineBerry I have never used C# sockets but should "tcpl.start" be called outside the while loop? I just keep looking at the code and it doesnt follow normal tcp socket flow.

Comment: using port 80 was my last test. I did try several ports, opening them in the firewall and disabling the firewall. I also tried to set a Specific port "9000" but it did not work. I always get host unreachable from the client side. I also never used sockets before so I am not sure how the normal tcp socket flow work.

Answer (score 1):

[After looking around some other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922907/get-socketexception-no-route-to-host-instead-of-the-expected-sockettimeoutex).The problem was that as long as the USB is connected to the device that I'am using for debugging, it always gives host unreachable, remove the USB and then the code works.

I'am not sure if this was the same problem with Bluetooth.